# How do you obtain the astrometric RA and Dec for earthsatellite objects

Tags: pyephem

Below is an example provided in the Pyephem documentation:

```
    iss = ephem.readtle("ISS (ZARYA)","1 25544U 98067A   03097.78853147  .00021906  00000-0  28403-3 0  8652","2 25544  51.6361  13.7980 0004256  35.6671  59.2566 15.58778559250029")
    gatech = ephem.Observer()
    gatech.lon, gatech.lat = '-84.39733', '33.775867'
    gatech.date = '2003/3/23'
    iss.compute(gatech)
    print iss.rise_time, iss.transit_time, iss.set_time
    2003/3/23 00:00:44 2003/3/23 00:03:22 2003/3/23 00:06:00
```

I have obtained the exact same result when I run the example, so I expect that I am doing at least this part correct.  What I want to find out is the astrometric position of the satellite in J2000 coordinates, so I can compare it against a star chart.  I tried the following code and the answer is dubious since a_ra and ra are identical.  I believe both a_ra and ra are given in the epoch-of-date instead of the a_ra being the astrometric solution in J2000.

```
    print iss.a_ra, iss.ra, iss.g_ra
    8:50:10.99 8:50:10.99 6:54:40.64
```

Is there a way to apply the precession/nutation to the topocentric ra and dec in pyephem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excellent question! Having reviewed the C code that underlies PyEphem, it looks like *both* the `ra` and `a_ra` values are already precessed to the epoch of your observer object (which in your case is the default of J2000). For your reference, this is the `libastro` code in question from `earthsat.c`:

```
if (epoch != EOD && mjd != epoch)
    precess (mjd, epoch, &ra, &dec);
op->s_ra = ra;
op->s_dec = dec;
```

It looks to me like this `.ra` and `.dec` value are *already* precessed. Letting this code stand was probably an omission on my part; it is likely that what I really ought to have done, but failed to see at the time, was to move those assignment statements to a position *before* the `if` statement, so that they would be un-precessed and therefore distinct from the astrometric RA and dec that get set a few lines later by code that I myself added.

So: for the moment, you are actually — if I am understanding PyEphem correctly — getting exactly the RA and dec you want, and can proceed with your project. Meanwhile, I will pursue that ticket and try to get `.ra` and `.dec` to start giving different numbers than `.a_ra` and `.a_dec`!